# Issues I have with making a navbar in CSS

Tags: html, css

I tried adding a navbar, and I use this.

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1920;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #b0fcbd;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  opacity: 70%;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #21ff46;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Yet, the navbar (the blackest part - the background is a bit lighter) starts out a few pixels below and to the right of when the page starts. Also, the Links are in the complete middle. I just want them centered at the top. Hope someone can help.

[image: The webpage.]

Comment: Could you edit your question so we get a working snippet with HTML and CSS

Comment: `align-items: start` if you want the links up top. Need more info to determine why the margin exists. Possibly padding from the parent element?

Comment: You need to reset your css [css reset](https://www.google.com/search?q=css+reset&rlz=1C1GCEB_enKR953KR953&oq=css+reset&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.3958j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: As a web developer, get to know and love the developer tools in the web browser of your choice, or better still, all of them. Inspecting elements will oftne show where mystery paddings and margins are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add reset css to your page. Glad it help!

```css
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

#app {
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100vw;
 background: #0f1114;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1920;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #b0fcbd;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  opacity: 70%;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #21ff46;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
    <a href="#news">News</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix your positioning issue, just set `margin: 0;` on `body`.

To align the navbar items at the top, you can set `align-items: start;` on `.topnav`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 1920;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.topnav a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #b0fcbd;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  opacity: 70%;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #21ff46;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

The extra pixels at the top / around the page are part of the default css that different browsers set

You can remove that with `margin:0` on `body`

```css
.topnav {
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
  justify-content: center;
}

body {
  margin:0;
}

.topnav a {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 30px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #b0fcbd;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 7px 16px;
  opacity: 70%;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #21ff46;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```